# OCISessionGet failing with Unicode

Tags: oracle, unicode, utf-16, oracle-call-interface

I have the following code for connecting to a Oracle-XE DB which is working as expected:

```
const char
*tns = "(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=127.0.0.1)
        (PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=XE)))",
*usr = "scott",
*pwd = "tiger";

err = OCIEnvNlsCreate(&envhp,OCI_THREADED, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, (size_t) 0
                     , (void**) NULL, 0, 0);
if(err != OCI_SUCCESS) return true;

err = OCIHandleAlloc(envhp, (void **) &errhp, OCI_HTYPE_ERROR, (size_t) 0
                    , (void **) NULL);
if(err != OCI_SUCCESS) return true;

err = OCIHandleAlloc(envhp,(void**)&authp, OCI_HTYPE_AUTHINFO,(size_t)0
      , (void **) NULL);
if(err != OCI_SUCCESS) return true;
err = OCIAttrSet(authp, OCI_HTYPE_AUTHINFO,(void*) usr,
                 (ub4)strlen(usr),OCI_ATTR_USERNAME, (OCIError *)errhp);
if(err != OCI_SUCCESS) return true;
err = OCIAttrSet(authp, OCI_HTYPE_AUTHINFO,(void*) pwd,
                 (ub4)strlen(pwd),OCI_ATTR_PASSWORD, (OCIError *)errhp);
if(err != OCI_SUCCESS) return true;

err = OCISessionGet(envhp, errhp, &svchp, authp, (OraText*) tns,
                    (ub4)strlen(tns), NULL, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, OCI_DEFAULT);
if(err != OCI_SUCCESS) {
    checkerr(errhp, err, __LINE__);
    return true;
}
```

Now that I want to support unicode I changed the following:

```
err = OCIEnvNlsCreate(&envhp,OCI_THREADED, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, (size_t) 0,
                      (void**) NULL, OCI_UTF16ID, OCI_UTF16ID);
```

And now I am getting ORA-12154 at OCISessionGet, so its not connecting anymore. What Am I doing wrong?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a case of bad Oracle documentation, if you look at the description of dbname for  [OciLogin2](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10646/oci16rel001.htm#LNOCI17118), you'll find this piece of information

> *The dbname must be in the encoding specified by the charset parameter of a previous call to OCIEnvNlsCreate().*

I'm guessing this is the case here as well even though the [OCISessionGet](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10646/oci16rel001.htm#LNOCI17123)  documentation does not state it,  so **short answer UTF encode your tns string**.

Comment: thanks replying. After converting the string to UTF16 I am getting **Error - ORA-12169: TNS:Net service name given as connect identifier is too long**. For UTF-8 the TNS string given above is same bytes. Any ideas?

Comment: How do you do the conversion ?

Comment: for utf16 using erlang unicode:charcters_to_binary/3 and then loading the byte string into the tns char array

Comment: do you zero terminate the string ? i.e. zero byte at the end

Comment: utf-8 and ascii strings (they are the same in my case) are both zero terminated, just checked it. For UTF-16 I don't know how appending zero _byte_ applies perhaps I need to add 0x0000 (or two 0x00s at the end) -- tried both, didn't work, same error

Comment: Does strlen() work correctly for unicode ? the dbname_len should be the number of bytes, not the number of characters.  "The length of dbname, in number of bytes, regardless of the encoding"

Comment: I had the same doubt so I also tried with bytes count providing manually! I am going to post soon how I tried. May be you can tell me if am missing something there

Comment: Ok, i'll check back later